# Displaying playing card suits in dark or light modes

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, darkmode, sf-symbols

Following Apple's guidelines I'm using SF_symbols to represent playing cards in my SwiftUI iOS app. The hearts and diamond suits are traditionaly red, but the clubs and spades suits are black.
This statement:

```
Text(Image(systemName: "suit.spade"))
Text(Image(systemName: "suit.heart"))
```

would ideally display the cards in their colours adjusting to dark mode as need be. Black/red in light mode and white/red in dark mode. However I can't determine which modifier to achieve this effect and I want to avoid custom algorithms to avoid clashes when users use their own non-standard palettes.

I have tried the modifier `.symbolRenderingMode` with different modifiers but this doesn't solve the problem.

- `.multicolor` which displays correctly in light mode, but spades are displayed black on a black background in dark mode, which is not very accessible.
- `.monochrome` but hearts are not displayed red.

Since Apple delivers the suit symbols multicoloured I'm optimistic I can rely on their algorithms without me having to code a work-around.

(as an aside, I'd prefer [4 colours as this is regarded as the most accessible mode](https://stackoverflow.com) for poor eyesight, helping distinguish clubs from spades, but I'd settle for two colors if Apple offered this as standard and it supported dark mode)

*** Update: @HangarRash 's solution is correct, but the Xcode preview does not reflect this as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WCn3.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following gives a black spade in light mode and a white spade in dark mode. And the heart is an appropriate shade of red for the given mode.

```swift
Text(Image(systemName: "suit.spade").symbolRenderingMode(.multicolor))
Text(Image(systemName: "suit.heart").symbolRenderingMode(.multicolor))
```

The ".fill" version of each symbol works as well.

[image]
[image]

Note that Xcode does not properly show this in the preview. See the correct results by running the app in an iOS simulator or a real device.

Comment: Thanks HangarRash. That was driving me crazy. Turns out the Xcode preview did not reflect this, even though the simulation does.